# Naming convention for methods on structure for multiple uses

Tags: c, naming-conventions, naming

I'm writing a little library and struggling with the naming conventions. There is a structure called `gk_Stream` defined as follows:

```
typedef struct gk_Stream {
    gk_Stream_writeProc write;
    gk_Stream_readProc read;
    void* data;                 // Pointer to data needed by read and write procedures.
} gk_Stream;
```

Now, I want to supply 2 built-in uses for this structure.

1. Reading/Writing from/to a `FILE*`
2. Reading/Writing from/to a buffer

I first called the functions like the following:

```
gk_Stream_initWithFile(gk_Stream* stream, FILE* fl);

gk_Stream_initWithBufferSize(gk_Stream* stream, size_t bufferSize);
gk_Stream_initWithStringAndBufferSize(gk_Stream* stream, char* string, size_t string_length, size_t buffer_size);
gk_Stream_deallocBuffer(gk_Stream* stream);
```

But another possibility would be to call them like this:

```
gk_Stream_file_init(/* */);
gk_Stream_buffered_initWithSize(/* */);
gk_Stream_buffered_initWithStringAndSize(/* */);
gk_Stream_buffered_dealloc(/* */);
```

What names do you think make most sense or look/sound best? What are the names you would want to work with when using the library?

Comment: I am pedantic about function/variable naming myself, but if naming is your main problem, then you're certainly living a good life, sir!

Comment: @EitanT Haha! No, that's not my only problem, but I do take the time to think about and, well, ask questions here! ;)

Comment: Consider switching to C++ or some other modern language with overloading.

Comment: Its just me, I no likey mixey :P ... You are mixing both camelCase and under_scores! Maybe stick to one ;) ... As mentioned it is left to you, there have been some post [like](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/27264/naming-conventions-camelcase-versus-underscore-case-what-are-your-thoughts-ab) [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608443/underscore-or-camelcase). just stay consistent

Comment: @JimBalter I'm aiming to learn more about procedural programming. I also want to make the library be useable for projects written in C, which is not possible when writing in C++. (shared libraries excluded)

Comment: @another.anon.coward I do only use this in C. The reason is, that C does not provide namespaces and methods. The names that are separated by underscores belong together, just look at  `gk.Stream.initWithBuffer` as a comparison. In Python, this would be for accessing the method `initWithBuffer` of class `Stream` in the module `gk`. ^^ (I usually prefer `underscore_names`.)

Comment: You can do procedural programming to your heart's content in C++. Anyway, it was just a suggestion; of course I know that C++ libraries with overloaded method names aren't usable in C. Sooner or later you will regret targetting that obsolete language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
gk_Stream_InitWithFile(gk_Stream* stream, FILE* fl);
gk_Stream_Deinit(gk_Stream* stream);
gk_Stream_InitWithBufferSize(gk_Stream* stream, size_t buffer_size);
gk_Stream_InitWithStringAndBufferSize(gk_Stream* stream, char* string, size_t string_length, size_t buffer_size);
```

underscores to separate "namespaces", CamelCase for function names. lower_case for variables.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
gk_Stream_file_init(gk_Stream* stream, FILE* fl);
gk_Stream_file_deinit(gk_Stream* stream); /* not sure if necessary */
gk_Stream_buffer_init(gk_Stream* stream, size_t bufferSize);
gk_Stream_buffer_initWithString(gk_Stream* stream, char* string, size_t string_length, size_t buffer_size);
gk_Stream_buffer_deinit(gk_Stream* stream);
```

When I hear or read "buffered", I think of that as the *method* used internally to improve performance when writing to/reading from things such as files or pipes. However, that's not what's going on here. Your code can either do I/O with a file or with a buffer, so it makes sense for the function names to differentiate between performing operations on a file vs a *buffer*, not file and *buffered*.

Edit: Oh, I forgot to explain one other thing; I also would prefer `deinit` to `dealloc`, as `deinit` is the natural companion to `init`. Deallocating is perhaps how you are deinitializing the stream, but all the user of your library needs to know is that they are deinitializing the stream.

Comment: +1 for the deinit instead of dealloc. I use the same convention in my library. It just sounds like a natural counter of init()

Comment: I like `_fini` as the opposite of `_init` (but `_deinit` is fine as well). But why do you need a separate `_deinit` for file and buffer? A single `gk_Stream_deinit` can handle both cases (with the idea that after initialization, you no longer care how you have initialized).

Comment: I agree in most cases a single `gk_Stream_deinit` would work and would be preferable, but I don't want to presume things about Niklas's framework. Since he suggested a `gk_Stream_deallocBuffer`/`gk_Stream_buffered_dealloc` but not something similar for files, I figured that there's something behind the scenes that would effect that decision.
However, if possible, I would definitely go for a `gk_Stream_deinit` function.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard/recommended naming conventions in C.

Use whatever you feel is best for code readability, consistent with the naming conventions followed in rest of the code/project.

Comment: Yes, whatever naming convention he choose to use, as long as he *stays* with it, is right.

Answer (score 1):

It somewhat depends upon the purpose of the string argument in the buffered case.

I'd probably go with something like:

```
gk_Stream_file_init(gk_Stream *stream, FILE *f);
gk_Stream_mem_init(gk_Stream *stream, size_t buff_sz, const char *initval, size_t initval_sz);
gk_Stream_mem_free(tk_Stream *stream);
```

And then allow a NULL initval.

Comment: I agree with allowing the NULL initval. What you (Niklas) are really looking for is an optional parameter, and allowing NULL to be passed as a parameter is pretty much the closest you get in straight C.